# Mouse drifting away with SendInput

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mouse

When I receive the coordinates with `GetCursorPos` I need to set them back to the coordinates.

Below is a code sample (1st scenario) that shows how one could achieve this.

```
for(;;)
{
    // get cursor position
    POINT Point;
    GetCursorPos(&Point);
    // send mouse input
    SetCursorPos(Point.x, Point.y);
    // sleep
    usleep(15000);
}
```

The above method uses `SetCursorPos`, which I don't intend to use. The code sample below (2nd scenario) should behave the same way, using `INPUT` and `SendInput`, but it does not (more below).

```
for(;;)
{
    // get cursor position
    POINT Point;
    GetCursorPos(&Point);
    // configure mouse input
    INPUT Input;
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;               // mouse input type
    Input.mi.dx = (Point.x * 65535) / 2560; // normalized x coordinate
    Input.mi.dy = (Point.y * 65535) / 1440; // normalized y coordinate
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE; // move absolute
    Input.mi.time = 0;  // let system decide
    Input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    // send mouse input
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    // sleep
    usleep(15000);
}
```

What I expect to happen in both scenarios:

- the mouse moves without being weirdly pushed into any direction

What really happens:

- 1st scenario: Expectation gets fulfilled
- 2nd scenario: The mouse drifts (1 pixel at a time) towards the *middle top* (note)

(note) I use a dual monitor setup, arranged side by side. Both Monitors have a resolution of 2560 x 1440. The *middle top* would be the top left corner of the right monitor.

This (in my opinion) clearly shows that I am at fault with using `SendInput`. How could I remove that weird behaviour?

Comment: The math is wrong. 65535 is an actual normalized coordinate whereas 2560 and 1440 are just outside. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much. Changed to 2559 and 1439 and it works...